# Slack bot ALWAYS gives missing_scope error

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I'm new to Slack bots so I went through their documentation and followed some tutorials on the internet but nothing seems to help. I'm trying to add a simple bot to a workspace I've just created, all I want is to make the bot post a message once it starts. Here is my code:

```
const SlackBot = require('slackbots');

const botToken = 'xoxp-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

const bots = async () => {

    const bot = await new SlackBot({
        token: botToken,
        name: 'orderbot'
    });

    console.log('adding event listener...');

    await bot.on('start', () => {
        console.log('posting message...');
        bot.postMessage('general', 'Feeling hungry?');
    });
};

bots();
```

**And in the `OAuth & Permissions` page, I've added ALL permissions to the token's scopes**. Running the bot, here is my output:

```
adding event listener...
/home/mohammed/OrderBot/node_modules/vow/lib/vow.js:105
            throw e;
            ^

Error: missing_scope
    at /home/mohammed/OrderBot/node_modules/slackbots/index.js:46:33
```

So apparently, the error is coming from the `.on` listener which is quite confusing and I can't understand why this is happening. What exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the module `slackbots` which I was using is not working properly (at least for me). I solved this issue by using `@slack/web-api` instead.